# Приложение падает NullPointerException. Проблема с Адаптером RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview, recyclerviewadapter

Всем привет. Уже часа два бьюсь и не могу понять в чем причина. Буду благодарен любой помощи.
Есть фрагмент, который инициализирует адаптер и назначает его RecyclerView (p.s. стрелочками >>>>> показал где ошибка выскакивает):

```
public class NewsFragment extends Fragment {
@BindView(R.id.recycler_view)
RecyclerView recyclerView;

private NewsAdapter adapter = new NewsAdapter();
private NewsViewModel viewModel;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    >>>>>>recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NewsViewModel.class);
    getNews();
}

private void getNews() {
    viewModel.getLiveDataNews()
            .observe(this, page -> {
                    adapter.addItems(page);
            });
}
```

}

И код самого адаптера:

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder> {

private NewsPage page;

@NonNull
@Override
public NewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_news, parent, false);
    return new NewsViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NewsViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(page.posts.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return page.posts.size();
}

public void addItems(NewsPage page) {
    this.page = page;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


static class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.news_image)
    ImageView newsImage;
    @BindView(R.id.news_title)
    TextView newsTitle;
    @BindView(R.id.news_body)
    TextView newsBody;

    public void bind(Post post) {
        GlideApp.with(itemView)
                .load(post.imageUrl)
                .centerCrop()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .into(newsImage);
        newsTitle.setText(post.title);
        newsBody.setText(post.body);
    }

    public NewsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}
```

}

Приложение падает с ошибкой:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: ru.mydomain.myappname, PID: 25593
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
                  at ru.protasovdev.cadethandbook.news.NewsFragment.onViewCreated(NewsFragment.java:32)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1439)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2215)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:649)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:167)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1238)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1086)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1616)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19150)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6115)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1723)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:788)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:648)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19150)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6115)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:223)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:141)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19150)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6115)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:400)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19150)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6115)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:223)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19150)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6115)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1723)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:788)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:648)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19150)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6115)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:223)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2772)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19150)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2476)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1440)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1694)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1321)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6763)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:894)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:696)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:880)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5697)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Расскажите, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: Вы забываете биндить `ButterKnife.bind(this, view);`. В доках есть примеры как и где это делается для разных классов UI: http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Comment: @woesss Большое спасибо. Действительно, забыл совсем про ButterKnife. Проблему решил.